# Apply Conditional Text Modifications Through a List of FlexTables

Tags: r, mapply, flextable, officer

I have a list of 32 flextables with 5 different columns. I want to apply the color and bold function to 2 separate columns, based on a condition.

My approach is as follows:

```
###Create a function that takes an input x (the flextable) and an input y (the values that will be conditioned on
f <- function(x,y){
    x <- color( x,i = y <= 0.05, j=4,color="red")
    x <- bold( x, i = y <= .05, j=4)
    x
```

I create the y values as follows. The tablerep contains a list of 32 dataframes and the column I want to condition on is column 4:

```
  highlight <- lapply(tablerep,function(i) sprintf('%.3f',as.numeric(as.character(unlist(i[4])))))
```

I then use the mapply function to apply the function to the list of flextables x, based on the conditional values y:

```
MyFT <- mapply(f,MyFT,highlight)
```

For some reason, my output looks like this:

```
> MyFT
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]        [,9]       
header     List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8     
body       List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8     
footer     List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8      List,8     
col_keys   Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5
caption    List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2     
blanks     Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0 Character,0
properties List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2     
           [,10]       [,11]       [,12]       [,13]       [,14]       [,15]       [,16]       [,17]       [,18]
```

instead of the list of flextables. Can anyone please provide insight as to why this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about `mapply` that reduces the result to a matrix because the default value of argument `SIMPLIFY` is TRUE. To stop that and get a list instead, use:

```
MyFT <- mapply(f,MyFT,highlight, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```